# What other elements apply styling, like body and paragraph do?

Tags: html, tags

I found that body tags, and paragraph tags add margins and spacing, so I was wondering what other elements have unique styling properties.

Also, what would be an good way to disable them? What I have now is:

```
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, {
  border: 0 none;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0 none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: What you want is a [reset stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major difference is some elements are "block" and some are inline. However, that can be changed as well.

```
a {
 display:block;
 height:100px;
 width:600px;
 margin:auto;
 background:url ...
}
```

So to answer your question all elements. Even your own ...

```
<script>
document.createElement("myelement"); 
</script>
<style>
myelement {
 display:block;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
}
</style>
<html>
<myelement>I've made my own standard - but it does not validate with html checkers</myelement>
</html>
```

This allows html5 elements to be created for non HTML5 browsers ... http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-make-all-browsers-render-html5-mark-up-correctly-even-ie6/

W3C does not want you to create myelements though.

Answer (score 0):

blockquote, em, strong are a few others. If you want to work with the assumption that nothing has style, you could set the defaults to `*{ }` as * selects all elements.

Comment: Could that slow down the browser processing, from adding properties to everything?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much every element (except span, I think) has a default styling. But other that have default margin/padding are `ul` and `ol`.

If you want to disable them, you can use the global CSS selector, *.

```
* {
    /* Default styles */
}
```